# Nested c-style loops in bash

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, nested

Can anybody explain why the following c-style loop in a bash script doesn't work as expected?

Script:

```
for ((i=0; i<3; i++))
do
    for ((j==0; j<3; j++))
    do
        echo "Iteration $i $j"
    done
done
```

Expected output:

```
Iteration 0 0
Iteration 0 1
Iteration 0 2
Iteration 1 0
Iteration 1 1
Iteration 1 2
Iteration 2 0
Iteration 2 1
Iteration 2 2
```

Observed output:

```
Iteration 0
Iteration 0 1
Iteration 0 2
```

This makes no sense to me. I guess the inner and outer loop "interfere" somwhow (very weirdly) with each other. Non-c-style for loops (with "in") do work as expected...

thanks
m.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, its because you wrote j==0 . hence only 1 iteration of the inner loop happens, because once j++ makes the value of j equal to 1, the equality j==0 is no longer true.

Answer (score 1):

```
for ((j==0; j<3; j++))
```

is this a typo just here, or do you really test j for equality to 0? That would maybe explain it...

Comment: Yes, it was a typo (not a typo while posting it here, a typo in my actual script) and it _is_ why it didn't work :$